# GestureDetector onVerticalDragUpdate work when rotating

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have a little spinner that I can rotate and it updates a value when you rotate upward and when dragning downwards it will decrease the value. But I have a issue with when the delta.dy comes over 90 degrees it start to update the value negative.

Here is how it works now:

```dart
    GestureDetector( onVerticalDragUpdate: isActive
    ? (details) {
        if (details.delta.dy > 0) {
            if (minutes == 0) {
                setState(() {
                finalAngle = 0.0;
                });
                return;
            }

    setState(() {
        now = now.subtract(
        Duration(seconds: 10));
        milliseconds--;
        getTimeDifferenceMinutes();
    });
    } else {
        setState(() {
            now = now.add(Duration(seconds: 10));
            milliseconds++;
            getTimeDifferenceMinutes();
        });
    }
    Offset centerOfGestureDetector = Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 3,constraints.maxHeight / 3);
    
    final touchPositionFromCenter = details.localPosition - centerOfGestureDetector;
    
    setState(() {
        finalAngle = touchPositionFromCenter.direction;
    });
    }: null,
    child: Transform.rotate(
    angle: finalAngle,
    child: isActive
    ? SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/a.svg") : SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/b.svg",),),);
```

I want it to work so when I start rotating it will increase the value until I start drawing it backwards.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! When writing questions, be sure to indent the code correctly, to make it more readable and have a better chance of getting an answer. To avoid doing it manually, you can copy and paste the code like normal text in the question, then select the code and click the format code button.

Comment: Ok thanks. Then I will fix the code indent.